# Q: Appium Inspector for ios9/xcode7

Tags: ios9, appium, xcode7

Is there a way to get the Appium Inspector to work for ios9/xcode7?

I know Appium Inspector is from appium.app, which is currently stuck on 1.4.8. I know to get appium tests working with ios9/xcode7, you need appium server at >=1.4.11.

However, I am unable to run the appium inspector anymore, and I need to update the element paths to some of my tests. Does anyone know of a way to get appium inspector working with the latest appium server, or an alternative element inspector tool?

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a script to create an Appium driver with desired capabilities
2. Run Appium server in command line mode
3. Run the script to create connection to Appium server
4. Execute Appium Inspector